# Skip validation of model attribute using Backbone.Validation

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, backbone.validation.js

I have a view that is rendered dynamically. It may have some inputs or may not have.
After a user fills everything and tries to send data I call `this.model.isValid(true)` ( or `this.model.isValid()` ) and it returns `false` even if the data from inputs is valid.

I think the cause is [Backbone Validation](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation) tries to validate attributes of inputs we did not render.

Is there any solution to skip model attributes if we have no [sticked](https://nytimes.github.io/backbone.stickit/docs/annotated/) elements of a view?

**UPDATE:**

My ***model*** is similar to this:

```
MyApp.module("RecordModel", function (RecordModel, MyApp, Backbone) {
    RecordModel.recordModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        validation: {
            inn: {
                pattern: 'inn',
                msg: MyApp.messages.inn
            },

            bik: {
                pattern: 'bik',
                msg: MyApp.messages.bik
            },

            uin: {
                pattern: 'uin',
                msg: MyApp.messages.uin
            },

            sum: {
                pattern: 'sum',
                msg: MyApp.messages.sum
            }

        }
    });
});
```

***Bindings:***

```
bindings: {

    '#uin': {
        observe: 'uin',
            setOptions: {
            validate: true
        },

        events: MyApp.Validation.events.inputEvents
    },

    '#bik': {
        observe: 'bik',
            setOptions: {
            validate: true
        },
        events: MyApp.Validation.events.inputEvents
    },

    '#inn': {
        observe: 'inn',
            setOptions: {
            validate: true
        },
        events: ParkingMate.Validation.events.inputEvents
    },

    '#sum': {
        observe: 'sum',
            setOptions: {
            validate: true
        },
        events: MyApp.Validation.events.inputEvents
    }
}
```

So for some reason we din't render `#sum` input for instance. As we haven't it got in our DOM, it doesn't exists in `RecordModel`, but backbone still tries to validate it. Or if we have this input in our DOM, everything works fine.

Comment: need some additional info about how is realized your model validation for these fields

Comment: Denys is right, please include a [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[How can I allow empty values but still validate if the user enters something?](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#how-can-i-allow-empty-values-but-still-validate-if-the-user-enters-something)

> By default, if you configure a validator for an attribute, it is
>   considered required. However, if you want to allow empty values and
>   still validate when something is entered, add `required: false` in
>   addition to other validators.
>
> ```
> validation: {
>     value: {
>         min: 1,
>         required: false
>     }
> }
> ```

If you can't let empty values (like at creation), [Backbone.validation overrides `isValid`](https://github.com/thedersen/backbone.validation#isvalid) adding features to the default behavior. What's interesting is the array parameter we can pass:

> ```
> // Check if name and age are valid
> var isValid = model.isValid(['name', 'age']);
> ```

With this, we can then validate only the fields that exist within the model at the moment:

```
model.isValid(_.keys(model.attributes));
```

Comment: See the update please. Your second solution is pretty nice, but instead of `model.attributes` I would try to collect rendered input ids and pass them as arguments in `model.isValid()` since ids of inputs and attribute names are matched.

Comment: @DmitrySoroka yes, your technique would work. My example using `_.keys` is just to demonstrate a way, but might not work out of the box in your context.